# Proving $(H \implies H) \implies G \quad \therefore \quad G$ using natural deduction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I'm stuck on this extra credit logic problem for my course...

> Prove
>
> $$(H \implies H) \implies G \quad \therefore \quad G$$
>
> using methods of natural deduction.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what does that // mean in your course

Comment: (H -> H) -> G  is the premise,

and G is the conclusion,

// is used as the conclusion indicator

Comment: Oh! You were \\ to skip line. I see now. Should there be a "therefore" infront of that last G?

Comment: I made an edit, is that more clear?

Comment: So I've never taken a formal logic course I only know what I have learned from math, and it is my knowledge that it is pretty different but would this work: Let P =(H $\implies$ H) then using the contrapositive of the premise we have $\neg G \implies \neg P$ which is equivalent to $\neg G \implies \neg( H \implies H)$ which is equivalent to $\neg G \implies H \wedge \neg H$ which is a contradiction by law of excluded middle so $G$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the meaning $\lnot a \vee b$ where ever an $a\implies b$ appears:
$$
(H\implies H) \implies G \\
(\lnot H\vee H)  \implies G \\
\lnot((\lnot H\vee H))  \vee G \\
(H \wedge \lnot H))  \vee G \\
\mbox{false } \vee G \\
G
$$

Comment: Hi! thanks for your help, this made things a lot more clear.

We also need to add justifications and line number references.

How would one go about this? Did you use material implication?

Comment: how did you get from 

¬((¬H∨H))∨G     to

(H∧¬H))∨G

Comment: He distributed the negation through..

Comment: *laughs* Do we even know the rules of inference for the natural deduction system?  Isn't the hallmark of natural deduction systems a rule of conditional introduction?  Your proof doesn't use conditional introduction.

Comment: @Doug Spoonwood: perhaps it means there will be less extra credit for this solution. The deduction in the answer is certainly not in natural deduction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction

Comment: @CarlMummert There's an old paper on a system of Copi which calls that system a "natural deduction" system.  http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1093894010  I don't have the edition of the textbook from where that system appears, but I do have a later edition of that textbook.  There is no rule of conditional introduction in it.  But, I'll just call this use of John A. Winnie's use of the term "natural deduction" anomalous.

Comment: looks more like a one-sided sequent system to me

Answer (score 4):

[Natural Deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction) refers to several deductive systems in first-order logic, and so without additional information it isn't clear which specific system is intended.

Written in tree form, and not writing out sequents, one possible derivation would look something like this (the MathJax formatting is not ideal, but it conveys the idea):
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\begin{array}{ll}
\begin{array}{cl}
\\ \\ \\
\hline
[H \Rightarrow H] \Rightarrow G{}
& u 
\end{array}
 &
\begin{array}{cc}
\hline
H & v \\
\hline 
H \land H & \land I \\
\hline
H & \land E \\
\hline
H \Rightarrow H & \Rightarrow I^{v}
\end{array}
\end{array} \\
\hline
G & \Rightarrow E\\
\hline
([H \Rightarrow H] \Rightarrow G) \Rightarrow G & \Rightarrow I^u
\end{array}
$$

The proposition in question, $([H \Rightarrow H] \Rightarrow G)\Rightarrow G$, is intuitionistically valid, so the proof should not require rewriting the implications in terms of disjunction and negation, and it should not require reasoning by cases based on the truth values of $H$ and $G$.

Comment: Did you ever play a game called WFF and Proof?  Natural Deduction reminds me strongly of the allowable proofs in that game.

Comment: @MarkFischler I've played some of the WFF and Proof games, but never any of the PROOF games in the kit that I have.  Layman Allen cites Fredrich B. Fitch's book on Symbolic Logic.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

What is the antecedent of the assumption?  Can you prove that antecedent?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you mean by natural deduction, I'm gonna assume you want a proof witouth using formalities at all:

$H$ has only two possible states, $T$ or $F$. Therefore $H \implies H$ can only be $(T \implies T) \equiv T$, or $(F \implies F) \equiv T$. So now we have  $T \implies G$. Since this statement is a premise, we are to take it as True, meaning  we assume $(T \implies G) \equiv T$. This will only if and only if $G \equiv T.$

Comment: "natural deduction" is a one of the standard deductive systems for first-order logic.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction